# How to download PhoneGap application to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap. I have developed a small PhoneGap application and it works fine in the simulator. Now I want to download it to my iPhone. How can I do this..? I'm using XCode4 and PhoneGap V1.0.0. I tried following the guidelines in PhoneGap site, but with no success. It seems that XCode doesn't detect my iPhone.
I don't currently have an Apple Developer license. Do I need to buy one to download my PhoneGap application to my iPhone..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.Without apple developer certificate you can't run the apps in device.Not only for Phonegap, If you want to load the app in device means, you need license.

Comment: Really.. this sucks.. I had to spend several hundred dollars to buy my iPhone in the first place and now I have to pay more do buy a license.. do you know any workarounds for this.. thanks..

Comment: For installing (as well as releasing )your own app (ie) app developed by you only need certificate.Others which are in apple appstore can be downloaded without your license.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a Apple Developer License in order to execute the app on your device.